# rerendering page with react-loadable and hydrate in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-loadable

In my project, am using react-lodable plugin for lazyloading js files and hydrate for server side rendering. but after pagelayout completes, the webpage re-rendering whole page on client-side.

re-rendering problem comes while serving html from server to client.

is this problem with react-lodable or any other issue?